# Dump All VAD of a process in Windows

Tags: windows-7, windbg

I wanna get some memory dump of a specific process.

I've found each windows process contain VadRoot in a EPROCESS.

I used windbg to get some information of this structure...

```
kd> dt nt!_MMVAD fffffa801b7011d0
   +0x000 u1               : <unnamed-tag>
   +0x008 LeftChild        : (null) 
   +0x010 RightChild       : (null) 
   +0x018 StartingVpn      : 0x7fefe440
   +0x020 EndingVpn        : 0x7fefe4b0
   +0x028 u                : <unnamed-tag>
   +0x030 PushLock         : _EX_PUSH_LOCK
   +0x038 u5               : <unnamed-tag>
   +0x040 u2               : <unnamed-tag>
   +0x048 Subsection       : 0xfffffa80`19f62640 _SUBSECTION
   +0x048 MappedSubsection : 0xfffffa80`19f62640 _MSUBSECTION
   +0x050 FirstPrototypePte : 0xfffff8a0`00b3ac28 _MMPTE
   +0x058 LastContiguousPte : 0xffffffff`fffffffc _MMPTE
   +0x060 ViewLinks        : _LIST_ENTRY [ 0xfffffa80`1b7a38c0 - 0xfffffa80`1aa6d6a0 ]
   +0x070 VadsProcess      : 0xfffffa80`1b7e8941 _EPROCESS
```

Its Win7 64bit.

I guess StartingVpn: 0x7fefe440 has contain the memory contents of this block.

But is that a virtual address? or physical address? i don't know

what it stands for...

Thanks.

Comment: If you want to get a memory dump of a process, why not attach WinDbg as user mode debugger and do `.dump /ma`?

Comment: More context, please.

Comment: Aha that would be a nice approach but i am implementing this techniques on the Virtual Machine Monitor. I am just testing it on the kernel mode windbg because i am actually newbie on the Winodws :(

Answer (score 1):

VAD is short for **virtual** address descriptor and VPN is short for **virtual** page number. So it's a virtual address, not a physical address.

It needs to be translated to a physical address using PTEs (page table entry).

Given a user mode address I found with a user mode debugging session:

```
0:032> !address
[...]
+   7ff`fffdc000   7ff`fffde000  0`00002000  MEM_PRIVATE MEM_COMMIT  PAGE_READWRITE   TEB  [~1; 13ec.10fc]

0:032> dd 7ff`fffde000 L8
000007ff`fffde000  00000000 00000000 00240000 00000000
000007ff`fffde010  0022b000 00000000 00000000 00000000
```

I can do this in a kernel debugging session using [LiveKd (SysInternals)](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/bb545021.aspx):

```
0: kd> !process 0 0 explorer.exe
PROCESS fffffa8012ce5b10
    SessionId: 1  Cid: 13ec    Peb: 7fffffd6000  ParentCid: 13c0
    DirBase: 3029e8000  ObjectTable: fffff8a006139d60  HandleCount: 1078.
    Image: explorer.exe

0: kd> .process /p /r fffffa8012ce5b10
Implicit process is now fffffa80`12ce5b10
Loading User Symbols
[...]

0: kd> !vtop 0 7fffffde000
Amd64VtoP: Virt 000007ff`fffde000, pagedir 00000003`029e8000
Amd64VtoP: PML4E 00000003`029e8078
Amd64VtoP: PDPE 00000003`00ebcff8
Amd64VtoP: PDE 00000003`0203dff8
Amd64VtoP: PTE 00000003`01ebeef0
Amd64VtoP: Mapped phys 00000002`ff44f000
Virtual address 7fffffde000 translates to physical address 2ff44f000.

0: kd> dd /p 2ff44f000 L8
00000002`ff44f000  00000000 00000000 00240000 00000000
00000002`ff44f010  0022b000 00000000 00000000 00000000
```

Note how the content of the virtual address (`dd`) is identical to the physical address (`dd /p`).

Comment: Yes and Yes.. so how could i translate that VPN to virtual address? 
at 64bit windows... Thanks :)

Comment: I'll try to describe with an example later. `!vtop`, `!ptov`, `.process /p` and `!pte` are related WinDbg commands.

Comment: Okay i am really looking forward your explanation. Thanks :) 
BTW i found that i could retrieve the virtual address just multiplied by 0x1000 to VPN at x86 not x64. Please give me explanation as 64bit versions. Really Thanks.

Comment: @JaeHyukLee: 0x1000 is 4k, the size of a page

Comment: Yes Yes its a page size right. but how about the x64 ?

Comment: @JaeHyukLee: added an example

Comment: Oh yes .. it's really good example.. but i am really sorry that i wanna do is doing that same things on the hypervisor level.. so i did those windbg stuffs but don't know which data structure contain those information especially mapped file name ... i cannot find that member even after i spent some time with windbg.. 
BTW i found nice paper about this one: VAD: A Detail Investigation into Process's Memory

Comment: They said i could find the name field inside the control_area data structure but can't find it on windbg, but i've found that Subsection is a control_area structure.. but anyway.. i can't find the name string in that structure.. please visit here this is part of my dump http://pastebin.com/qDBPSr9M

Comment: @JaeHyukLee: ok. We're expanding the question with each additional piece of information you give in comments. Please describe in detail what you are doing and what you want to achieve. See: you didn't ask "how to convert virtual address to physical address" in the question. You didn't mention anything about the hypervisor in the original question. You didn't mention that you're analyzing a memory mapped file. And it seems our guesses do not meet your needs. So please, describe the question in more detail so that we can help you.

Comment: @JaeHyukLee: some kernel structures are "encrypted" (used to be a simple XOR encryption) and you can't simply do a `dt` on it. Maybe http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/ is a better place to ask such questions

Comment: Oh.. yes it was my fault.. sorry :(

Comment: Oh really ? Actually what i really wanna know was the logic that windbg prints the all VAD information when i type !vad address.

Comment: Because i wanna implement process memory dump capability in hypervisor level using kvm or xen whatever :)

Comment: @JaeHyukLee: e.g. google `_HEAP_ENTRY.Encoding` which holds the key to XOR with

Comment: @JaeHyukLee: note that a memory dump of virtual memory also includes memory that was paged out to disk, so you would read some pages from physical memory and remaining pages from swap file. Quite a hard task...

Comment: Oh.. its interesting .. :P So it would be encrypted as XOR with key .. Then.. how could i know that whether it is encrypted or its data_structure is obsolete? i mean it would be possible that Windows developer changed that datastructure right ?

Comment: Ohh... i think i am asking too many things in this one question... i realized that i am talking about what i've asked.. haha

Answer (score 1):

**locate process**

```
lkd> !process 0 0 explorer.exe
PROCESS 8a1908d0  ...... Image: explorer.exe
```

**set process context**

```
lkd> .process /p /r 8a1908d0
```

**view reqd module**

```
lkd> lm m explorer
start    end        module name
01000000 010ff000   Explorer   (deferred)
```

**get the vadroot for a virtual address in the current process context**

```
lkd> !vad explorer 1

VAD @ 8a120ed0
  Start VPN         1000  End VPN     10fe  Control Area  8a81ab80
  FirstProtoPte e23e9048  LastPte fffffffc  Commit Charge        3 (3.)
  Secured.Flink        0  Blink          0  Banked/Extend        0
  File Offset          0  
      ImageMap ViewShare EXECUTE_WRITECOPY 
      ReadOnly 

ControlArea  @ 8a81ab80
  Segment      e23e9008  Flink      00000000  Blink        00000000
  Section Ref         1  Pfn Ref          4d  Mapped Views        1
  User Ref            2  WaitForDel        0  Flush Count         0
  File Object  8ab28240  ModWriteCount     0  System Views        0

  Flags (90000a0) Image File HadUserReference Accessed 

      \WINDOWS\explorer.exe

Segment @ e23e9008
  ControlArea     8a81ab80  BasedAddress  01000000
  Total Ptes            ff
  WriteUserRef           0  SizeOfSegment    ff000
  Committed              0  PTE Template  8a81ac3000000420
  Based Addr       1000000  Image Base           0
  Image Commit           2  Image Info    e23e9840
  ProtoPtes       e23e9048

Reload command: .reload explorer.exe=01000000,ff000
```

dump all the vads for a current process context

```
lkd> !vad 8a120ed0 0
VAD     level      start      end    commit
8a03b1d8 ( 3)        e50      e51         0 Mapped       READONLY           Pagefile-backed section
8a6fe240 ( 4)        e60      e6f         0 Mapped       READWRITE          Pagefile-backed section
................................
89c86600 ( 5)        ff0      ff0         1 Private      READWRITE          
8a120ed0 ( 0)       1000     10fe         3 Mapped  Exe  EXECUTE_WRITECOPY  \WINDOWS\explorer.exe
.................................
8a87bb18 ( 7)       26d0     2733         0 Mapped       READWRITE          \Documents and Settings\Admin\Local Settings\History\History.IE5\index.dat

8a74b420 ( 0)      3e1c0    3ec52        10 Mapped  Exe  EXECUTE_WRITECOPY  \WINDOWS\system32\ieframe.dll

8abfa398 ( 1)      7ffde    7ffde         1 Private      READWRITE
```

**Total VADs: 1231, average level: 5, maximum depth: 4294967295**